# Script that opens cmd from spyder

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am working on a text adventure with python and the issue i am having is getting spyder to open a interactive cmd window. so far i have tried `os.systems('cmd / k')` to try and open this which it did but i could not get any code to run and kept getting an app could not run this file error. my current code runs off a import module that pulls the actual adventure from another source code file. how can i make it to where only one file runs and opens the cmd window to play the text adventure?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Cmd windows are hidden by default because there are some packages that open lot of them while running code (e.g. `pyomo`).

To change this behavior, you need to go to

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Advanced settings > Windows adjustments`

and deactivate the option called `Hide command line output windows generated by the subprocess module`.

Comment: i can make that work for my personal pc but i want it to where the code opens in cmd for the other person upon opening if possible almost how when u call on a module it opens the new file in the console

Comment: Sorry but that's not possible. Please instruct the other person to change the option I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a similar situation, developing code for a research group with heavy Spyder usage. I came up with this workaround to force usage of the vanilla Popen class regardless of whether or not it is run from Spyder (full disclosure I have not tested it very aggressively):

```
import subprocess
try:
    from spydercustomize import SubprocessPopen
except ImportError:
    SubprocessPopen = subprocess.Popen
else:
    SubprocessPopen = SubprocessPopen.__bases__[0]

process = SubprocessPopen()
```